# Changing formatting only for the bibliography section

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

is there a way of changing the page formatting only for the bibliography of a huge tex project (a Ph.D. Thesis)?

Specifically, I would like to reduce the left and right white space of the pages only for the bibliography (with the purpose of inserting more biblio in a single page). Better, if I can also scale down the size of the letters (only in that section, of course). Any hint to achieve the goal is highly appreciated.

Here the code

```
\pdfminorversion=5 % default is 4; 5 or more required for 

\pdfobjcompresslevel
\pdfcompresslevel=9 % default is 9
\pdfobjcompresslevel=2 % default is 0

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%...
\begin{document}

%...

\bibliographystyle{something_here}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ, which font and font size you employ, and how you (or the document class you employ) set the height and width of the text block. E.g., do you employ the `geometry` package?

Comment: is there a way of sharing files (in StackExchange) in order to show the information needed?

Comment: You may edit your posting to show, e.g., the preamble of the LaTeX document.

Comment: ...updated by adding the useful part of the latex code

Comment: Any instructions in your document regarding margin widths? Does your document load the `geometry` package? What about line spacing: Is the document single-spaced? If not, how do you modify the line spacing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `adjustwidth` environment from the `chngpage` package.

Try the following MWE.

```
% changepageprob.tex  SE 570925
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-2cm}
\footnotesize
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\lipsum[3]
\end{adjustwidth}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The two arguments to `adjustwidth` are the amounts to be added to the left and right margins. A negative value will reduce the margin.

Inside the `adjustwidth` I used `\footnotesize` to reduce the font size.[image]

[image]

Comment: it works (+1). However, there is a strange effect because the right page and the left page of the book have different margins. As such, your solution messes up a bit the page formatting so it cannot be used in my thesis. Is there a way of taking this problem into consideration?

Comment: @Leos313 Read the `chngpage` documentation for more information (`> texdoc chngpage`).

Comment: @Leos313 Try the `adjustwidth*` environment instead of `adjustwidth`